# Append text to Value column in pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-2013, custom-formatting

I need to append the UOM, "hrs" to a list of value columns in the pivot table without affecting the summation that is being carried out. For this I've used the custom format cell option **##" hrs"** which works great but some of the values in the column contain decimals (o.5, 8.3 and so on). I don't want to change these values.. Instead I want to append the "hrs" text to each of these values, example: 1 hrs, 8.3 hrs, 10.5 hrs..

Is there any way for me to achieve this using the custom format cell option?

P.S. Apologies if it's a very simple solution m(_ _)m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need conditional formatting.

*In this example, the numbers will range from A1 down.*

Highlight the cells, starting at A1
Go to **Home**, **Conditional Formatting**, **New Rule**, and then **Use a Formula to Determine Which Cells to Format**.

For whole numbers:
For the formula, use `=MOD(A1,1)=0`
For the format, select **number**, go to **custom**, and type `#" hrs"`

For decimals:
For the formula, use `=MOD(A1,1)<>0`
For the format, select **number**, go to **custom**, and type `#.#" hrs"`

if you want commas, then the first format would be `#,#" hrs"` and the second would be `#,#.#" hrs"`

Answer (score 1):

use 0,00" hrs" as custom format cell option